Optimizing WebSocket Event Broadcasting with RabbitMQ and Redis
Context:
I have multiple servers to which clients can make WebSocket connections. Whenever a user makes a change that should be propagated to other clients connected to different servers, I use RabbitMQ to broadcast the event. All servers receive the event and, based on some business logic, decide whether to send a message to their connected clients or ignore the event.
Issue:
This approach requires broadcasting every event to every server because we don't know beforehand which server has the client connections that need the update. I considered using a distributed Redis setup to store connection request details in a way that would allow me to determine the appropriate server to broadcast the message to. However, this is causing a significant load on Redis.
Question:
How can I optimize the process of broadcasting WebSocket events to the correct servers without overwhelming Redis? Are there any design patterns or alternative approaches that can help reduce the load on Redis while ensuring efficient event propagation to the appropriate clients?
